# How can I call a specific keymap to draw within my AddonPreferences?

Tags: python, add-on

The add-on I've written defines several custom hotkeys, allowing the user to call custom menus created by the add-on. To be more user-friendly, I'd like to make it easy for the user to change the hotkeys for these menus without needing to dig through the massive keymap list under **User Preferences > Input**.

And so I have created **AddonPreferences**, in which the user can adjust settings for the add-on.

Is there a way to pull in, and draw the specific keymap item (from **Input**) within the **AddonPreferences**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're likely the first person who has attempted this, and it looks like its quite possible;

Notes

- Save this script to your addons dir with a unique name (ending with `.py`)
- The keymaps are added as is normal for an addon.
- There is **one bug** at the moment, pressing the 'X' buttons isn't properly removing them. *(needs further investigation we should be able to fix)*
- Finally - this uses a part of the API we consider internal, so its not guaranteed to work in future versions (realistically it probably wont change any time soon though).

Script:

```
bl_info = {"name": "KeyMap Test", "category": "Object"}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, AddonPreferences
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty

# this is an internal API at the moment
import rna_keymap_ui


class ExampleAddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    # this must match the addon name, use '__package__'
    # when defining this in a submodule of a python package.
    bl_idname = __name__

    filepath = StringProperty(
            name="Example File Path",
            subtype='FILE_PATH',
            )
    number = IntProperty(
            name="Example Number",
            default=4,
            )
    boolean = BoolProperty(
            name="Example Boolean",
            default=False,
            )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is a preferences view for our addon")
        layout.prop(self, "filepath")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, "number")
        row.prop(self, "boolean")

        col = layout.column()
        kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
        for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
            km = km.active()
            col.context_pointer_set("keymap", km)
            rna_keymap_ui.draw_kmi([], kc, km, kmi, col, 0)


class OBJECT_OT_addon_prefs_example(Operator):
    """Display example preferences"""
    bl_idname = "object.addon_prefs_example"
    bl_label = "Addon Preferences Example"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        user_preferences = context.user_preferences
        addon_prefs = user_preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

        info = ("Path: %s, Number: %d, Boolean %r" %
                (addon_prefs.filepath, addon_prefs.number, addon_prefs.boolean))

        self.report({'INFO'}, info)
        print(info)

        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_keymaps = []

# Registration
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_addon_prefs_example)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExampleAddonPreferences)

    # Keymapping
    kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    km = kc.keymaps.new(name="3D View", space_type='VIEW_3D')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("object.editmode_toggle", 'NUMPAD_SLASH', 'PRESS', shift=True)
    kmi.active = True
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("object.transform_apply", 'NUMPAD_SLASH', 'PRESS', shift=True)
    kmi.active = True
    addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_addon_prefs_example)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExampleAddonPreferences)

    # handle the keymap
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks so much.

Comment: With the recent API changes, that are so far undocumentated, how can I go about this?

Comment: Updated, only very minor changes, see `rna_keymap_ui` use.

Comment: In Blender 2.8 the keymaps are not persisted when doing it this way. Any ideas?

Comment: [Another useful source.](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-draw-a-custom-keymapitem-properties/13059/4)